# Issue with result of a find function in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a problem with a script in bash. My for function is using the results of the find function.

Long story short: in SSH, find the function returns 2 results and in a bash script a single result.

I tried both of the following codes.

```
for f in $(find $path -name *.properties)
do
echo $f
done
```

OR

```
list=$(find $path -name *.properties)
for f in $list;
do
echo $f
done
```

In the specified path there are several folders and files, two of the files have the extension that i am looking for. If I run one of these commands in SSH I find both files, but if I run the command from a bash script the result contains a single file.

The for function is working fine, the problem is the find function. I run the following code in a script bash and i still have one result.

```
list=$(find $path -name *.properties)
echo $list
```

I run the following code in SSH and I found 2 files:

```
[root@was85 ~]# for f in $(find $path/temp/ -name *.properties); do echo $f
> done
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Try: `find $path -name '*.properties'` (i.e. with quotes)

Comment: "$path" too for good measure. Also can you show us the paths to the files you are searching for and the value of `$path`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using `BASH` better to use this `while` loop using `process substitution` and **proper quoting** and use `-print0` option:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
   echo "$f"
done < <(find "$path" -name '*.properties' -print0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If using `bash` 4 or later, use the `globstar` operator rather than a vanilla call to `find` to simply recurse through a file hierarchy.

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in "$path"/**/*.properties; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

(If the body really *is* just `echo $f`, then `printf "%s\n" "$path"/**/*.properties` will suffice instead of using the loop.)