# cat-ing files of certain extensions in subdirectories

Tags: bash, loops, cat

I have a directory `parallel/` that contains subdirectories that contains files ending with `*.en` extensions.

Doing this will get me the list of files i need.

```
find parallel/ -name "*.en" -type f
```

Now I would need to `cat` all these files to get a combined file, i.e.

```
cat *.en > all.en
```

I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```
$ for i in (find parallel/ -name "*.en" -type f): do cat $i ; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

$ for i in ((find parallel/ -name "*.en" -type f)): do cat $i ; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Is there a way for me to iterate through all subdirectories and "cat" all of them into a single file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close; just lacking a dollar sign.

To make bash evaluate a command and get the output; use `$()`:

```
for i in $(find parallel/ -name "*.en" -type f); do cat $i ; done
```

`$()` is equivalent to, but better and safer than the older backtics

```
var=`cmd` #do not use!
```

Comment: Should i do `do cat $i>>all.en`?

Comment: it's giving `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'`

Comment: there was another minor typo: after the for() there should be `;` , not `:`

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke `cat` in the `find` itself using `-exec` option:

```
find parallel/ -name "*.en" -type f -exec cat {} +
```

To redirect it to a file use:

```
find parallel/ -name "*.en" -type f -exec cat {} + > all.en
```

As per `man find`:

```
-exec utility [argument ...] {} +
       Same as -exec, except that ``{}'' is replaced with as many pathnames as possible 
       for each invocation of utility. This behaviour is similar to that of xargs(1).
```

Comment: what does `{} +` mean?

Comment: `{}` is placeholder for each file found by `find` command and `+` is command terminator

Comment: Advantage of using `+` is more efficiency as forked processes are combined into a single process (if possible).

Comment: Also if you want to properly loop through the files from `find`'s output then [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26237843/548225)

Answer (score 0):

```
cat parallel/*/*en > all_en.txt
```

Comment: If there are more subdirectories inside subdirectories in parallel, this method will not include them